# Clipping a geotiff file where it does NOT overlap with a shapefile

Tags: gis, gdal

I have a geotiff file which overlaps with a shapefile. To clip for the overlapping part of the tif file, I can do this:

```
gdalwarp -co compress=deflate -dstnodata 255 -cutline shapefile.shp  original.tif overlap.tif
```

But how can I clip for the *non*-intersecting part? That is, I want to create the complement of `"overlap.tif"` w.r.t. `"original.tif"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdal_rasterize to burn a value where the shapefile overlaps the file. It works on an existing file, so make sure you use a copy.

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 255 shapefile.shp copy_of_original.tif
```

This burns a value of 255, setting `-a_nodata 255` doesnt work on my version of GDAL. If you need it to be a real nodata value using `gdal_translate` with `-a_nodata 255` afterwards would do the trick.

Gdal_rasterize also has a convenient `-i` flag which inverts the shapefile.

Comment: Hi Rutgers... gdal_rasterize is not quite what I want - which is basically a clip of the complement of the overlay.